# "Can't reach database server" Trying to connect Google Cloud SQL to PostgreSQL Prisma Database

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, prisma

I'm trying to use a PostgreSQL database with Prisma for the first time in my project. However, I'm failing to connect to the Cloud SQL instance I created on Google Cloud. When I run `npx prisma db push`, I'm getting the error:

```
Please make sure your database server is running at `34.86.23.139`:`5432`.
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1: prisma db push
```

I made sure the database server was running, and was able to successfully connect to it using Cloud Shell. The public IP address of the server is `34.86.23.139`, the name of the database is `test-db`, and the connection name is `test:us-east4:test-db`. Given that the connection string should be in the formal of `postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE`, I made this within .env:

```
//.env

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://myemail@gmail.com:mypassword@34.86.23.139/test-db"
// I also tried DATABASE_URL="postgresql://myemail@gmail.com:mypassword@34.86.23.139/test:us-east4:test-db" but same error.
```

And this is my schema.prisma:

```
// prisma/schema.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Thing {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm a newbie so go easy on me :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to connect with psql as a test.  Presumably Prisma isn't using "cloud shell", so your test shouldn't be either.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL instances are configured to block all traffic to the public IP unless you specifically allow an IP using [Authorized Networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks).

Alternatively, you can run the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) next to your application and it will create a listener on localhost that proxies traffic to your instance without having to configure Authorized Networks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CloudSQL Auth Proxy (corresponding to the "Cloud SQL connections" option of your Cloud Run service's configuration), the connection has to go through a Unix socket. The socket is automatically available in the service container at the path `/cloudsql/*connection-name*` where *connection-name* is the connection name of the Cloud SQL instance (ex: `project-id:region:instance-name`, available on the overview tab). See [this quick start](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-cloud-run#node.js:%7E:text=INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET%3A%20Set%20to%20/cloudsql/YOUR_PROJECT_ID%3Aus%2Dcentral1%3Aquickstart%2Dinstance.) guide for more informations.

According to PrismaDB [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/mysql#connecting-via-sockets), you need to change the value of the `DATABASE_URL` env var to include the path to the Unix socket (the host has to be *localhost* in this case):
`mysql://*user*:*pwd*@localhost/*database*?socket=/cloudsql/*project-id:region:instance-name*`

Hope it helps!