# Connecting Google App Engine to a Cloud SQL (Prisma) Postgres instance (through Bitbucket CI/CD)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, prisma, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm deploying a Google App Engine with a connection to a PostgreSQL CloudSQL instance, managed by Prisma ORM. All this I'm doing through the Bitbucket CI/CD. However I'm experiencing difficulties with setting-up this connection.

This is the error that I'm bumping into... (I've left out the security sensitive variables). The error occurs in the build step of the Google App Engine deploy image provided by Atlassian here: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy/src/master/

```
> prisma migrate deploy
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "mydatabasename", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `/cloudsql/my-project-id:europe-west1:my-instance-name`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at /cloudsql/my-project-id:europe-west1:my-instance-name`:`5432``.
```

I followed the following docs of Google: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard to connect through a Unix socket, but without luck. Also configured all the necessary IAM Roles.

**Environment:**

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname?host=/cloudsql/my-project-id:region:my-instance-name"
```

This `DATABASE_URL` is injected in schema.prisma like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Anyone that has experience deploying this specific tech stack, and knows how to set-up this connection?

Comment: Can you share minimal reproducible steps like how you are connecting using `prisma` and what variables you have in you `.env`(excluding PI), config files etc to replicate. Also have a look at this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369433/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75363992/18265570)

Comment: @RoopaM Thank you for reaching out, I've added more context. Currently, I'm trying out this approach https://github.com/edosrecki/google-cloud-sql-nodejs-connector-example/blob/3b5492637f581f9f8919b78fc83fbdf247684d12/src/prisma/index.ts but without much luck unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried changing `DATABASE\_URL` to `"postgresql://username:password@postgres/dbname?host=/cloudsql/my-project-id:region:my-instance-name"` or to `"postgres://${DB\_USER}:${DB\_PASS}@${DB\_HOST}:${DB\_PORT}/${DB\_BASE}?host=${CLOUD\_SQL\_CONNECTION\_NAME}"` as mentioned in [previous link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369433/18265570)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75294376/11715259

Answer (score 0):

Prisma does support connecting over a Unix socket.

See https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/postgresql#connecting-via-sockets.

It looks like you need to add a trailing slash,e.g.,

```
postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/database?host=/cloudsql/my-project-id:region:my-instance-name/
```